# In a two dimensional array, how do I check if two elements are sharing a vertical/diagonal line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, matching

```
 [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, %, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ %, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]
```

I have an 8x8 'board' and want to check whether the % signs are on the same vertical line. I know how to check if they're on the same horizontal line (in the same array), but I can't figure out how to check for diagonals and verticals.

Here is my full code:

```
var whiteQueen = [2, 5];
var blackQueen = [5, 0];
var danger = false;

var board =
[
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
];


for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //plot white queen
  if (whiteQueen[0] === i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j ++) {
      if (whiteQueen[1] === j) {
        board[i][j] = 'x';
      }
    } 
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //plot black queen
  if (blackQueen[0] === i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j ++) {
      if (blackQueen[1] === j) {
        board[i][j] = 'x';
      }
    }
  } 
}

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //reset board number guide
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (typeof board[i][j] == 'number') {
     board[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
} 

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //re-plot queens
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (board[i][j] === 'x') {
      board[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var sameLineCount = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    if (board[i][x] == 'x') { 
      if () // no idea how to register a matching line/diagonal
      sameLineCount += 1;
    } 
  }
}

/*[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]*/
```

So basically it's a chess board and I'm taking an array of coordinates and checking whether or not either of the queens are in danger. I'm getting kind of confused with all the for loops and I'm not exactly sure if I'm going about this in the right way.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You need to post the code snippet of what you have tried so far here. External links to code snippets is not allowed in SO.

Comment: You just need to check if the index number of the first property is equal to the index number of the second property. I can provide a code example if you can post the shortest relevant code snippet of what you have tried so far here.

Comment: My mistake. Post edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the positions of the 2 signs you're looking for and check:

> if (x1 == x2) then they're on the same Horizontal Line
>
> if (y1 == y2) then they're on the same Vertical Line
>
> if (|x1 - x2| == |y1 - y2|) then they're on the same Diagonal

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to figure it out.